# Adding elements "like" and "comments" to the Facebook Like Box

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-comments

The facebook like box allows me to show the feed of a group, but it doesn't show the likes or comments for each post, nor does it allow a logged in Facebook user to leave a comment on a post.

I have been unable to make sense of the Graph API (I'm not a programmer), I will keep trying, but meanwhile I wanted to ask if anyone knows of a way to import a group's facebook wall onto an external website, with full likes and comment functionality, as opposed to current methods which show how to import a facebook wall with stripped down functionality.